# Django circular depenceny ForeignKey vs ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

For a project I have a couple of Django apps. 
The goal is that a company or a contact can contain an unlimited number of contact information. (phone, email, addresses)

I figured it would be a good choice to create a `core` app where I put models like Phone, Address, Language, Country, etc...
I wanted to put these in a `core` app because they will be used in several apps thoughout the project.

Second I have a contact_management app where the models Company and Contact are.

So this is what it looks like

#### core / models.py

```
from contact_management.models import Contact, Company    

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='phone_numbers')
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='phone_numbers')
```

#### contact_management / models.py

```
from core.models import Language

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
```

This ended up in a circular dependency and the error `Cannot import Language`

So after that I started using many2many fields so I could reverse the dependency.

#### core / models.py

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

#### contact_management / models.py

```
from core.models import Language

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(Phone, blank=True, null=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    phone_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(Phone, blank=True, null=True)
```

This might work but the admin doesn't allow me to use `TabularInline` in the admin to show the details or let me update the fields from the Contact or Company form.

Plus I would not really prefer a ManyToManyField because every contact info instance (phone, email) only has one contact or company.

#### contact_management / admin

```
class CompanyPhoneInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Company.phone_numbers.through

@admin.site.register(Phone)
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["company_name", "bank_account_number", "tax_id",
              "chamber_of_commerce_id", "active"]
    inlines = [CompanyPhoneInline, ]
```

Maybe it is just a detail I am missing here or I should follow another design pattern. I hope someone could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run into these problems often because of the order of the apps you have in `INSTALLED_APPS` or for the particular case in your post.

Django recommends following in such cases ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.
>
> ...
>
> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly specify a model with the full application label.
>
> This sort of reference **can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies** between two applications.

So instead of using `Language` you could use `'core.Language'`:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey('core.Language')
```

Here, `core` is the `app_label` and `Language` is the model class name.

I recommend that you use this full application label (string version) to define your related fields such as `ForeignKey`, `ManyToMany` etc everywhere. so you never run into these problems.

Comment: The right solution, but the problem has nothing to do with the order in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Yes this problem doesn't but you can have it if the order is different.